# Too many records returned from MSSQL stored procedure called by pytds

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure in an MSSQL database that looks like the following:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[VideoSearchThorough]
(
  @SearchString NVARCHAR(4000) = ''
  , @Offset INT = 0
  , @Limit INT = 100
  , @UserId INT = 0
  , @ProviderId INT = NULL
  , @StatusType INT = 0
  , @StartDate datetime = NULL
  , @EndDate datetime = NULL
  , @UseUpdatedDate bit = 0
  , @PltValue INT = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @OrderClause VARCHAR(200) = 'CreatedDate DESC'

    IF @Limit IS NULL OR @Limit > 100 SET @Limit = 100

    CREATE TABLE #tmpsrch(
      VideoId BIGINT,
      UserId INT,
      VideoUrl VARCHAR(500),
      Title VARCHAR(1000),
      Description VARCHAR(5000),
      CreatedDate datetime,
      EffectiveDate datetime,
      ExpirationDate datetime,
      Height INT,
      Width INT,
      Duration decimal(10, 2),
      ThumbnailUrl VARCHAR(200),
      Keywords VARCHAR(200),
      IsEnabled bit,
      IsDeleted bit,
      ProviderId INT,
      ProviderName VARCHAR(200),
      ProviderLogo VARCHAR(200),
      ProviderTrackingGroup INT,
      ProviderIsMediaSource bit,
      ProviderContentIsPrivate bit
    )

    INSERT INTO #tmpsrch(VideoId, UserId, VideoUrl, Title, Description, CreatedDate, EffectiveDate, ExpirationDate, Height, Width, Duration, ThumbnailUrl, Keywords, IsEnabled, IsDeleted, ProviderId, ProviderName, ProviderLogo, ProviderTrackingGroup, ProviderIsMediaSource, ProviderContentIsPrivate)
    EXEC VideoSearch @SearchString=@SearchString, @MatchType=0

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tmpsrch (NOLOCK)) = 0
    INSERT INTO #tmpsrch(VideoId, UserId, VideoUrl, Title, Description, CreatedDate, EffectiveDate, ExpirationDate, Height, Width, Duration, ThumbnailUrl, Keywords, IsEnabled, IsDeleted, ProviderId, ProviderName, ProviderLogo, ProviderTrackingGroup, ProviderIsMediaSource, ProviderContentIsPrivate)
    EXEC VideoSearch @SearchString=@SearchString, @MatchType=1

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tmpsrch (NOLOCK)) = 0
    INSERT INTO #tmpsrch(VideoId, UserId, VideoUrl, Title, Description, CreatedDate, EffectiveDate, ExpirationDate, Height, Width, Duration, ThumbnailUrl, Keywords, IsEnabled, IsDeleted, ProviderId, ProviderName, ProviderLogo, ProviderTrackingGroup, ProviderIsMediaSource, ProviderContentIsPrivate)
    EXEC VideoSearch @SearchString=@SearchString, @MatchType=2

    SELECT TOP (@Limit) *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tmpsrch (NOLOCK)) AS ResultsAvailable FROM (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) AS rowId,
            *
        FROM #tmpsrch
    ) AS results
    WHERE results.rowId > @Offset

    DROP TABLE #tmpsrch
END

GO
```

And in my python 3 code, I'm calling this stored procedure via the `pytds` module:

```
with pytds.connect(db_server, db_name, db_user, db_pass) as connection, connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.callproc('VideoSearchThorough', ['search string', 0, 20])
    response = cursor.fetchall()
    result = []
    for rowData in response:
        row = {}
        for columnIndex, columnData in enumerate(cursor.description):
            row[columnData[0]] = rowData[columnIndex]
        result.append(row)

    return result # This contains 84 result records
```

However, when I execute the following SQL in my SQL Operations Studio Client:

```
VideoSearchThorough 'search string', 0, 20
```

..only 20 records are returned. I want only 20 records as I am passing `20` as the limit (the third parameter provided to the `VideoSearchThorough` stored procedure).

However, a total of 84 records are returned when using the `pytds` module in Python 3.7, why the difference?

Comment: You're not sending the limit to the procedure. The default is 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see in your Python code where your're setting the @Limit variable: if you aren't setting that, it's using the default value of 100, but there are only 87 records to return.